# Disk IO slower when outstanding IO requests are less than 32

Tags: database-performance

I moved the databases from one server to another and general remark from users is that its slower. The old server was on windows 2003,64 bit, SQL 2005 Ent edition(32 bit) whereas new one is Windows 2008 R2, 64 bit, SQL 2005 Std edition-64 bit. I ran SQLIO on both and found that throughput is slower on new one when outstanding IO requests are less than 32 and faster when IO requests are more than 32. This really puzzles me. How do Interpret this behavious. I can send results of SQLIO and SQLIO analyser, but don;t know how to upload here.

Comment: It sounds like the new server has a slower disk subsystem but handles high contention better.

Comment: I've just spoken SAN manager he said both disks (old and new) on are on same SAN. How can we imporve the throughput on New server with low contention?